# Trace flags in Azure SQL Hyperscale

Tags: sql, azure

We are migrating from SQL Server 2008 R2 on-premise (in-house) to Azure SQL Hyperscale. Within on-premise trace flags (1118, 3042, 3226) are enabled. I have read they are not supported in Azure SQL Hyperscale.

When the SQL Server databases are migrated successfully, how to enable or replace trace flags equivalent?

Note: Azure SQL Hyperscale is chosen as the database size is more than 10Tb. And that Managed Instance does not support more than 4Tb for Business critical.

Comment: What is the reason for those trace flags? You probably don't need them anymore.

Comment: Looking at this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 it's unlikely you need them anymore, not that they even apply as there is a new architecture, and no you can't use tract flags in any SQL PaaS platforms

Comment: 3042 is to save backup file space? Why do you think you need this in Hyperscale?

Comment: _Starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x) this behavior is controlled by the SET MIXED_PAGE_ALLOCATION option of ALTER DATABASE, and trace flag 1118 has no effect. For more information, see ALTER DATABASE SET Options (Transact-SQL)._ You need to do a lot more research on your migration plan